# Saving some contenteditables localstorage - - -

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to save more than one entry of contenteditable content into my localstorage for a Chrome extension. My current code saves just one contenteditable section fine, but when I try to add another Id of a seperate contenteditable section it either deletes all the saved information or doesn't do anything at all. I'm pretty novice in JS, so I hope I'm just making a simple mistake. My html looks like this:

```
<div id = "content">
<div id= "tcontent" contenteditable="true" data-ph=" Make a note . . . "
style= "height: 300px; overflow: auto"></div>
<div id = "content2">
<div id= "tcontent2" contenteditable="true" data-ph= " Make a note . . . "
style= "height: 300px; overflow: auto"></div>
</div>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad); function onLoad() {
checkEdits();
}
function checkEdits() {
if(localStorage.userEdits!=null) {
    document.getElementById("tcontent", "tcontent2").innerHTML += localStorage.userEdits;
}
};

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
e = e || window.event;
console.log(e.keyCode);
      saveEdits();

};
function saveEdits() {
var editElem = document.getElementById("tcontent", "tcontent2");
var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;
};
```

Basically this code will only save one (the content I place first into the getElementbyId). Isn't there a way to save both of the 'content's?
I've been playing around with all my little knowledge of javascript I have but can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong or what I should be doing here.

Much thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.getElementById is a method that only takes one element's id. You are currently trying to pass two strings to the method. That will not work.

Please refer to the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Also, you must assign the innerHTML of each element individually to each piece of saved content in localStorage.

Granted that you are fairly new to the Language I do not want to overcomplicate the answer for you. With that said, please find below your code with a few modifications to be able to save both pieces in localStorage respectively:

```
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad); function onLoad() {
    checkEdits();
}

function checkEdits() {
    if(localStorage.userEdits1!=null) {
        document.getElementById("tcontent").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits1;
    }

    if(localStorage.userEdits2!=null) {
        document.getElementById("tcontent2").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits2;
    }
};

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    saveEdits();
};
function saveEdits() {
    var editElem1 = document.getElementById("tcontent");
    var editElem2 = document.getElementById("tcontent2");

    localStorage.userEdits1 = editElem1.innerHTML;
    localStorage.userEdits2 = editElem2.innerHTML;
};
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks for explaining it and giving me the example. Much appreciated for a JS newcomer :)